# How can I use key value of foreach as property value of an object?

Tags: php

I want to print all the properties from an object.

Is there a way to use the key value as a property value of a object? instead of using `get_object_vars`.

Error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$key

**Update** Example

```
foreach ($arrayOfArrays as $key => $arrayOfValues) {
   foreach($arrayOfValue as $key => $value){
      $object = (object) $value;
      echo $object->$key;
    }
}
```

Example of $arrayOfValues

```
Array
(
    [key1] => "value1"
    [key2] => "value2"
)
```

Example of $value

```
stdClass Object
(
    [scalar] => "value1"
)

stdClass Object
(
    [scalar] => "value2"
)
```

Comment: `$object->$key`.

Comment: @JonStirling That doesn't work, you get the value prefixed with the '$' symbol.

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: What's the type of `$value`? Why do you need to convert it to an object?

Comment: `$key` is the key of the array, what does it have to do with properties of the object?

Comment: Yeah, the type cast is screwing it up.

Comment: @bansi Yes, I tried it,

Comment: @Barmar it's the type of an array.

Comment: Then why don't you write `$value[$key]` instead of casting it to an object?

Comment: Could you show an example of `$array` and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: @Barmar I know how to get values from arrays. I was just wondering if it could be done using objects. But thanks for the support.

Comment: How is the key of the array related to the property of the object?

Comment: Put the content of `$array` into the question.

Comment: I don't think there's any way other than `get_object_vars`.

Comment: What's the point of converting the array to an object? `$arrayOfValues[$key]` should be enough to access the data you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in your case it was a simple typo:

```
$arrayOfArrays = [[
    'key1' => 'value 1',
    'key2' => 'value 2',
]];

foreach ($arrayOfArrays as $key => $arrayOfValues) {
    $object = (object) $arrayOfValues;
    echo $object->key1; // you ommited the 1;
}
```

As the other mentioned you can use directly the array. No need to convert it to object:

```
foreach ($arrayOfArrays as $key => $arrayOfValues) {
    echo $arrayOfValues['key1'];
}
```

If you want to display all the keys of that array you can simply use something like:

```
foreach ($arrayOfArrays as $key => $arrayOfValues) {
    $object = (object) $arrayOfValues;

    foreach (array_keys($arrayOfValues) as $unkownKey) {
        echo $object->$unkownKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your third solution prints out all the values without any errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `scalar` instead of `key`:

```
<?php

$array = ['hi', 'there'];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $object = (object) $value;
    // print_r($object);
    echo $object->scalar;
}
```

Working [example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba46446399bec279a6a2d5070c236f6129669eea).

---

As docs say on:

> For any other value, a member variable named scalar will contain the value.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: His comment says that `$value` is an array, so it won't get `scalar` as the property.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. I've tested a code with an array within the array. Wierd PHP behaviour to say the least.

Comment: As I've tested in this example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ebf5f29ca0595532cf1704c9a26aab4b1cd9e9f2

Comment: What's so weird? An associative array converts to an object with the same properties.

Comment: Test the code from the sandbox, you'll see. See the `print_r` outputs as well.

Comment: @omerowitz It work and prints out all the values. But it still throws an error. Undefined property: stdClass:$scalar.

Comment: @melkawakibi Yes, actually. It works. If a `value` or `scalar` doesn't exist in one of the iterations of the array, it will produce an error. Latest working snippet: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f39c27bf8bf0a51e3735b7ad062015d0b6c3964f

Comment: Can you fix your answer?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, we still have to guess at the data structure. Here is my best guess at a complete example:

```
$array = array(
    (object) "value1",
    (object) "value2"
);

foreach ($array as $name => $array_value) {
    $object = (object) $array_value;
    foreach ($object as $property => $value) {
        echo $object->$property . "\n";
    }
}
```

Try it yourself at [repl.it](https://repl.it/J0YE/2)